# How to add external resource to classpath in a Java web app (Spring, preferably)

Tags: java, spring, jboss

In my webapp, I use a jar that accesses a file called `env.properties` as follows :

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/env.properties");
```

We are externalizing all our property files (i.e. placing them outside our source code and outside of JBoss folder), but this jar (which we cannot modify) expects this property file on the classpath.

I've read that we can place this folder (`resources`) on the classpath using JBoss modules, but I don't want to place any property file inside the JBoss folder.

I'm keeping my property files at :

`/app/property-files/some.properties
/app/property-files/resources/env.properties`

My aim is to either get JBoss to add this location to its classpath, or programmatically add this location to the classpath through Java so that the jar can access this file.

Comment: Maybe you can copy the file from your external location to the expected one?

Comment: I have to place the files at an external location (outside the JBoss folder) because I want to avoid dependency on JBoss in case I shift to another server tomorrow. Adding the external folder to classpath seems the only way out