# Spring: which event is fired BEFORE beans are loaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wish to progammatically place a file in `WEB-INF/classes` folder **before** beans are loaded. `ContextRefreshedEvent` seems to be fired when context has been fully loaded. Is there any way to execute some code **before** any bean is loaded in Spring?

Comment: You cannot do that. You cannot place files inside your archive.

Comment: Can I change the content of a file placed at WEB-INF/classes, at least?

Comment: No. Nor should you be wanting that. What if some malice code would be able to replace your classes inside your web-archive...

Comment: I wanted to add some external property files to my classpath, but being unable to do so, I thought maybe I can get write the property file on the classpath itself. I discussed this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651147/how-to-add-external-resource-to-classpath-in-a-java-web-app-spring-preferably

Comment: As stated you cannot write to it, nor will it work as the classpath has already been build and the properties are loaded.

Comment: If your properties are in an external location then the right way to do it is to create your own `PropertySource` implementation to load them from wherever they may reside.